# Cutting Polygons in QGIS at a specific distance from a feature in another layer

Tags: qgis, vector, polygon-creation

I would like to be able to cut polygons such as the one below, in QGIS, at a set distance either side of a specified feature on another layer, in this case a footpath line from OS Mastermap.

In this way I would then effectively have a buffer along the lines that could represent a woodland ride network, for example. In this case it is a very simple linear feature, but they are often much more complex, and can be very time-consuming to cut out. Ideally I need to retain the original polygon as this will be used as well.

Is it possible to cut a polygon in this way, or would I have to create the new polygons as buffers along the line and then cut these from the existing polygon?

[image: Screengrab of polygon to be cut]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this workflow you will need [refFunctions](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/refFunctions/) plugin, to use `geomintersects()`.

1. Open attribute table of your Polygon layer.
2. Activate Field Calculator.
3. Tick on `Update existing field` and select `<geometry>`from the pull-down menu.
4. Provide this expression: `difference($geometry, buffer(geom_from_wkt(geomintersects( 'Your_LineLayerName', '$geometry')), 20))`

Please modify `Your_LineLayerName` which is your (path) layer, and `20` (buffer size) as required.

NB. Since the change is made instantly and irreversible, please be careful and keep a copy of your original Polygon file.

Comment: Thanks Kazuhito, that works great, but it seems to cut AND remove the buffered line out of the existing polygon - is it possible to retain it instead as a new polygon?

Comment: @JimS-W If you use `intersection()` instead of `difference()`, it will give you the buffered part. But I am afraid it does not help you to obtain both geometries (difference and intersection) in single action.

Comment: That's fine, I should be able to get what I need by combining the 2 in a scratch layer I think. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

You will need to `buffer` the selected line (path) at the distance you require and then cut those out of the other polygon using `difference`.

If it was an operation you needed to do very often then it would be worth writing a python script to carry out both operations together.

Comment: Thanks iant, I thought that might be the case.

I do have to do it pretty regularly but I don't really know where to start with writing script, beyond just basic queries. Would it be fairly straight-forward do you think?

Comment: I have been attempting to repeat this operation using the expression difference($geometry, buffer(geom_from_wkt(geomintersects( 'Your_LineLayerName', '$geometry')), 20)) , in QGIS 3.2.1, but it no longer seems to work. 

It either returns the error "Eval Error: 'QgsGeometry' object has no attribute 'exportToWkt'", or just tells me the layer I am trying to cut with doesn't exist. Any suggestions @Kazuhito? I have installed the refFunctions plugin.

Comment: Please ask a new question rather than use a comment

Comment: Will do @Ian Turton. I've found the Enable tracing - > offset function covers most of what I need to do now in any case.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of QGIS (I'm using 3.2.1) it's now possible to do this much more quickly and easily using the 'Offset' function within the Snapping Toolbar (from the drop-down menu next to 'Enable Tracing'):

[image]